# C++ Inputting numbers into array and outputting them

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand C++ as I'm new.
The below code crashes every time I run it. As far as I know, it should output 0 to 9. 
Stating that i = num[i] I know is pointless however adding this extra code makes it crash.
Why?

```
    int num[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        i = num[i];
        cout << num[i];
    }
```

Edit - Thanks, guess I didn't see that little error. Seems obvious now...

Comment: why should it print 0 to 9? You never assigned anything to the array elements

Comment: try `num[i] = i;`.

Comment: Why are you using an array at all?

Comment: Just experimenting, thanks user1810087

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and the initialisation of `num[]`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight The code itself was easy enough to understand regardless of the main function. Question, why would I need to initialise the num array? And thanks Ill look into  the link.

Comment: "_why would I need to initialise the num array_" if `num` was in global scope - you wouldn't, since it would be default-initialized to `0`. If it is in local scope (i.e. in a function, like `main`), it would contain indeterminate values. Such an answer would be answered, in detail, in any [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: If you don't initialise the contents of `num[]` and it was declared in your function, then the reads from it will be *undefined* - you might get negative values or nasal demons.  Running your program under Valgrind will help you catch errors such as that; also make sure you've enabled as many compiler warnings as you can bear.

Comment: It's possible that you meant `num[i] = i;` - is that the case?

Comment: @TobySpeight There was no error in what I wrote, but what I intended to have happen was solved by doing that. I usually make dumb mistakes. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int num[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        i = num[i];
        cout << num[i];
    }
```

In the above piece of code you haven't stored anything to the array you declared. So it would print some random values out.

The following would work as you think :

```
int num[10]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){

        cout << num[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning `num[i]` which is undefined to `i`. Then you're incrementing i, and accessing element `i` (undefined) of `num` in the next iteration of the loop, which is only 10 items long.

In effect you're trying to access memory at position `num[1978253]`, which you have no control over.